# I want to make less heavy a big vertical photo without loosing resolution

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I need to send a big long vertical photo in a MMS but every time I try, it loose all the quality.

The photo is very heavy due to her dimension, how can I make that same photo less heavy without loosing resolution?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have Photoshop, save for web.

[image: menu]

And adjust your settings to find a good balance between quality/file size

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To reduce an image file size (kb) you have three options:

1. lower the resolution of the image (ppi)
2. reduce the dimensions of the image.
3. use a more damaging compression scheme (like a lower quality jpg setting)

There's no other "magic" solution.

Of course, there's always the possibility of a juice cleanse to get that "heavy" image to drop some lbs.

Comment: Juice cleanse is the way to go!  He's a braver man than I, calling a woman "heavy"...